# UniqueEntity validation Fails - Symfony?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Let say i have two entities `college` and `department` where college has many departments(one to many). my validation.yml looks like

```
App\CollegeBundle\Entity\College:
        - departments:
            - Valid: ~
App\CollegeBundle\Entity\Department:
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity:
            fields: [department_name, HOD ]
```

when i trying to persist the college entity with n-number of departments `Unique Entity` validation works, later when i am trying to add another new `department` entity to `college` entity and persist `unique entity` validation fails and i am getting `unique key violation` , what mistake i made?

i am using `csv import` feature on each row of csv file i made an ajax call for example in my controller

```
 $department = new Department()     

if( isset( $record["department_name"] )  && strlen( trim( $record["department_name"] ) ) > 0 )
{
   $department->setDepartmentName($record["department_name"] );
}

if( isset( $record["hod"] )  && strlen( trim( $record["hod"] ) ) > 0 )
{
   $department->setHod($record["hod"] );
}

//set college
$department->setCollege($college)

//adding departments
$college->addDepartment($department)

$validate = $this->get('validator')->validate($college);
if($validate->count())
{
   return [ "status" => "error" ]
}
else
{
   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
   $em->persist($college);
   $em->flush();

   return [ "status" => "success" ];
 }
```

Comment: Please show us the code when you save please

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri i added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't create a new college (so you have already a college entity) but only a new department try this:

```
//set college
$department->setCollege($college)

$validate = $this->get('validator')->validate($department);
if($validate->count())
{
   return [ "status" => "error" ]
}
else
{
   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
   $em->persist($department);
   $em->flush();

   return [ "status" => "success" ];
 }
```

Instead if you are creating a new college also I advise you to create first a new College, persist It and flush, take its Id and create the new Department